# Read Multi Line Text File To Single Line With "/n" As Text?

Tags: python

test.txt is multi line (1 URL in each line)

```
http://website.com

http://website2.com
```

Reading test.txt

```
f=open("test.txt","r")
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
 keywordurl = "\n".join(line.strip() for line in f)
f.close()
```

The result is 
keywordurl will look the same as the text file multi line list. Now here is the problem:
If I want to use keywordurl in javascript value

```
self.br.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl00_phMainContent_KeywordForm_ControlPanel_txtKeywords').value = '%s';" % keywordurl )
```

I will face an error because it's a multi line value. I need to set the value in 1 line with "\n" as a text at each end of line like this:

```
http://website.com\nhttp://website2.com\nhttp://website3.com
```

Can anyone help me with the python code to make it look like above the working solution?

Comment: just change `\n` to `/n` in your join statement ... but thats not a very good delimitter especially when working with urls ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley sorry it was a typo I need \n a valid new line in javascript as well but write it as text :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the backslash in keywordurl.

Replace

```
keywordurl = "\n".join(line.strip() for line in f)
```

By

```
keywordurl = "\\n".join(line.strip() for line in f)
```